# Losing data frame cells in foreach loop

Tags: r, parallel-processing

similar questions have been posted but I can't find one that actually addresses the problem i'm having, so sorry if this is not distinct enough.

I'm processing a for loop in parallel using doParallel and foreach. The core of my code is:

```
combinedOut <- foreach(i = 1:48, .combine=rbind)    %dopar%
{
    ##function that builds a data frame row with 6 columns, adding different columns seperately
    ##data frame is called out18
    out18[i,]
}
```

When I run this is as a for loop my output (out18) is correct, and [in this form.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vNLYR.png)

However when I run it as a foreach, only the first and last column contain the right values (referring to combinedOut here). I have no idea why its only the middle four columns that are empty.

Essentially I want to copy the entire ith row of every foreach iteration and combine them all into one data frame at the end.

Thanks for any responses.

Comment: What type are your outputs in `out18`? Possibly foreach is combining the outputs as matrixes instead of data.frames.

Comment: The first column for both is 'Factor w/ xxx levels' and last column for both is int.
The four middle columns for combinedOut are 'logi'
The four middle columns for out18 are 'num'